# PHP extensions (like `mongodb`) is not loading for a specific PHP version (e.g., 8.1) enabled by Laravel Herd on macOS?

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, php-extension, laravel-herd

I'm using Laravel Herd on macOS with multiple PHP versions managed by Herd (7.4, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3). I verified that PHP 8.1 is active using `php -v`.

Following the Herd documentation for adding extensions (https://herd.laravel.com/docs/1/advanced-usage/additional-extensions), I installed the `mongodb` extension using `brew install php` and `sudo pecl install mongodb`.

I found `mongodb.so` in two locations:

- `/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20230831/mongodb.so`
- `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.4/pecl/20230831/mongodb.so`

However, upon installation, the extension line `extension=/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20230831/mongodb.so` was automatically added to the Herd `php.ini` for the 8.3 version. And mongodb extension is showing fine on php 8.3 nad listed after running `php -m`, even though the active version is php 8.1.

As I need the extension on php 8.1, When I manually added the same line to the Herd `php.ini` for the 8.1 version, I encountered the error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20230831/mongodb.so'
```

Can anyone give some idea on the recommended approach to install php extension for individual php version enabled by laravel herd?

Comment: Laravel Herd provides individual php.ini for each php version.

Comment: PHP extensions are compiled to match specific versions of PHP. You are loading the wrong extension version. Download the correct version of mongodb.so for each PHP installation.

Answer (score 1):

Each version of PHP requires its own extension versions. The same version of a module can work very well on PHP 8.1 and not on PHP 8.3.

You must therefore download the appropriate version specific to your PHP 8.1.

Check the [MongoDB compatibility tables](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php-drivers/#language-compatibility) depending on your version of PHP and MongoDB.